# Wordpress Super Slow Server Response 11GB Wordpress DB

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

My site at https://powersportsauction.com/product-category/motorcycles is on WP Engine and my server response time is reported at 1.8 seconds. See here - http://screencast.com/t/16OXwZmV

I think this is related to the size of my DB at 11GB. Is there a way to audit server response time to identify what specifically is slowing down the response? i.e routing, expensive db queries, etc.

The tech support team obviously takes no blame and I am well aware that minifying css/js and removing render blocking css/js out of the head will help overall speed but that's not what I'm asking.

I specifically want to know if there is a way to audit server response time, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the best tool for this kind of work is https://newrelic.com/ which will profile your application code and SQL queries continually. New Relic is expensive but very useful.

There are some free tools you can use to do spot-checking. I recommend Percona Toolkit or the Query Analyzer in Percona Cloud Tools.

Here's a blog about using Query Analyzer to pinpoint a bad query in Wordpress: https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/16/analyzing-wordpress-mysql-queries-query-analytics/

Since that blog was published, Percona discontinued the PCT service and released the software for anyone to use for free (but you have to host it yourself) as: https://www.percona.com/software/database-tools/percona-monitoring-and-management

It's probably easier to use the SQL query digest tool in Percona Toolkit. Read https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/12/29/identifying-the-load-with-the-help-of-pt-query-digest-and-percona-server/

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of way to provision / profiling your server performance, i.e Newrelic https://newrelic.com/

Which can breakdown your response time down to code level (which line of code actually running longer time), database response time etc etc